# JSP output ends with NullPointerException after 680 KB

Tags: jsp, nullpointerexception, websphere, response

I have a legacy JSP that has scriplets, I am doing testing of it in our application on Websphere 7.0.0.13. The same JSP, with exact same data works correctly in Weblogic 10.3.2.

The JSP uses code to produce a lot of HTML output + javascript. On Websphere is failing consistently with a NullPointerException in the middle of the JSP's output. Everytime it fails it fails around 680 KB of data in the page.

If I view source from a browser, the last line of output gets cutoff, something like this

> ";document.getElementById( 'start.123.12345.67891.123123123' ).appendChild(divTag);exError 500: java.lang.NullPointerException

No other output. Logs report an uncaught NullPointerException from my JSP.

Most of this output is generated using the page's JspWriter `out.println();` inside of scriptlets.

I have tried adding a page directive for autoflush=true thinking it may be a buffer issue but it still fails.
    <%@page autoFlush="true" %>

Comment: Do you have a Stacktrace to figure out the exact line in the JSP you get the NPE ?

Comment: If I look from the stacktrace to the generated .java file for the line, it is this:   `out.write(_jsp_string55);` and this is the declaration of _jsp_string55 variable `private final static char[] _jsp_string55 = "\r\n</html>\r\n".toCharArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this after reviewing the generated java file using the [keepgenerated JSP engine config parameter](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0403_johnson/0403_johnson.html) and using the line number from the stack trace of the NullPointerException.

The original developer set the JspWriter out to null in a scriplet at the end of the file.

```
<% 
  out = null;
%>
</html>
```

In the Websphere generated .java file the out variable is set to null before something like this:

```
out = null;
out.write(_jsp_string55);
```

If i comment out the `out = null;` statement in the JSP file, this resolves the issue.

FYI - I've also created a test JSP that writes out far more than 680 KB by just looping and printing out to the JspWriter. I found that no  matter the size of the output I could not reproduce the same NullPointerException.